# Excel xlsx files in drive with google sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

does somebody manage to use xlsx files with Google Sheets API?
The thing is that the user wants to keep using Excel to edit the sheet and upload the updates with google file stream cause it's a more convenient way. I'm building an app that interacts with google sheets API.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `The thing is that the user wants to keep using Excel to edit the sheet and upload the updates with google file stream cause it's a more convenient way.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike said, could you explain better your situation? Also you should consider using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference)

Comment: @Tanaike You can do this with https://sheet2api.com

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick responses! and sorry for the lack of context. Well the thing is that google API for spreadsheets only works if the file is saved explicitly as an "Google Spreadsheet", not if is in other format as xlsx (Excel).

Comment: So at last, I convienced the user to save the file as a google sheet with the benefit that he could edit in collaboration with his partners and if he wanted to use Excel for editing, he has to download the file from drive as an xlsx and then upload again. I know this last part is a little bit tedious but for the moment that will work.

Comment: @Richard Thank you for your support. Unfortunately, although I cannot still understand about OP's goal, I think that it will be useful for OP.